# Cygwin и Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, linux, windows, cygwin

Нужно срочно написать программу на С для связки процессов (pipe(), fork() и т.д). Одна проблема - я на Windwos 7, а Linux пока установить не могу. Посоветовали установить Cygwin, а дальше что делать - понятия не имею. Неожиданный вопрос - что дальше? Как связать Cygwin и VS, если первый вообще поможет скомпилить Linux-проект на винде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы путаетесь, cygwin — это замена Visual Studio и остального MS окружения для людей которые хотят зачем-то быстро почувствовать that Linux feeling™, фактически не ставя Linux. Там есть отдельный компилятор gcc.

К тому же сейчас можно легко поставить Linux на виртуальную машину и проделать все что вам нужно в ней.

Comment: Хм, теперь ясно. Ресурсы машины не позволяют ставить виртуалку, да и я пишу программы для Линукса редко

Comment: @master_clown Можете поставить ось параллельно (в другой раздел диска).

Comment: @Athari, у меня так и было, до тех пор пока не стало ясно, что 160 Гб для каждой оси не слишком мало.

Comment: cygwin — это не столько замена, сколько **линукс-интерфейс** ко всему тому, что есть в Windows, включая Visual Studio. Насколько помню, gcc в cygwin как раз запускает средства Visual Studio для компиляции.